# How rearrange the bars on the x-axis in R

Tags: r

I am new to using R and would appreciate help on a code.

I am attempting to re-arrange the bars on the x-axis of my plot. Most sources I have seen provide ways to do this in ascending/ descending order, or alphabetically; or for ggplot (I need to use barplot).

My data table currently looks like this...

```
       Expected       Observed  
Avg       50             12 
Good      48             50 
Bad       77             82 
Worse     12             12
```

When I plot this table using the code

```
barplot(data.table, beside=T,
        ylim=c(0,100),
        col=c("blue", "red")
legend("topright", c("Expected","Observed"), pch=15, 
       col=c("blue","red"), 
       bty="n")
```

The x-axis of the bars Avg, Good, Bad, Worse are arranged in alphabetical order. I am trying to re-arrange them into the order of Bad, Worse, Avg, Good. It was suggested I turn these into factors, but I am met with an error every time I ty to do so saying...
"$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"
Using the code

```
data.table$Expected<- as.factor(data.table$Expected)
```

and

```
data.table$Avg<- as.factor(data.table$Avg)
```

Using dput(head(daily)) results in:

```
structure(c(275.939393939394, 292, 57.0909090909091, 47, 90.3939393939394, 
80, 47.5757575757576, 52), .Dim = c(2L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Expected", "Observed"), c("average", "best", "better", 
    "good")))
```

Any way to re-arrange these with code instead of turning them to factors?

Thank you!

Comment: Turning the x-axis into factors in the correct method, but without seeing your code it is impossible to diagnose the cause of the error.

Comment: I added the code, thank you for your input!

Comment: You don't want to change Expected or Avg.  Can you provide a sample of data.table using the `dput` function?  Edit your question by adding the output of `dput(head(data.table))`

Comment: updated! thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reproducible example. I suggest you to add this code before plotting, which will reorder the columns in your data.

The order will then be: average, good, better, best.

```
data.frame<-data.frame[,c(1,4,3,2)]
```